# How to use the mean value of a column and another column to plot a line graph?

Tags: r

I have a pretty big data frame and trying to make a line graph.

```
Ferret ID   Vaccine Day Temperature Weight
558 None    -2  100.6   1420
558 None    -1  101.5   1420
558 None    20  102 1450
547 Vaccine 31  101.5   1080
547 Vaccine 32  100.8   1100
548 Vaccine -2  100.7   1290
548 Vaccine -1  101.2   1300
548 Vaccine 0   101.6   1320
548 Vaccine 1   101.5   1031
548 Vaccine 2   101.9   1310
548 Vaccine 3   101.6   1300
548 Vaccine 7   101.7   1300
548 Vaccine 14  102.2   1280
....
```

I want the independent variable to be day and the Dependent variable to be the average temperature of which the Vaccine is "None"

I've tried "sapply" but didn't work>.....
it is actually my homework and it's the final week I really appreciate if someone could help...

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three solutions. In the future, it helps to show what you have tried so we can tailor the answer to your methods and/or preferences.

First, your data is not well-formatted: having spaces in column names is discouraged in R, so for this example, I'll instead use

```r
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
ID  Vaccine Day Temperature Weight
558 None    -2  100.6       1420
558 None    -1  101.5       1420
558 None    20  102         1450
547 Vaccine 31  101.5       1080
547 Vaccine 32  100.8       1100
548 Vaccine -2  100.7       1290
548 Vaccine -1  101.2       1300
548 Vaccine 0   101.6       1320
548 Vaccine 1   101.5       1031
548 Vaccine 2   101.9       1310
548 Vaccine 3   101.6       1300
548 Vaccine 7   101.7       1300
548 Vaccine 14  102.2       1280")
```

Second, I'll assume that all of your `Day` values are integral; to do otherwise will cause problems with the grouping, as it would not be obvious (given what we know) that anything other than integer days would be meaningful.

Okay, here's a hasty base-R way to do things:

```r
x1 <- x[ x$Vaccine == "None", ]
x2 <- do.call(
  rbind.data.frame,
  by(x1, x1$Day, function(a) data.frame(Day = a$Day[1], AvgTemp = mean(a$Temperature, na.rm=TRUE)))
)
x2
#    Day AvgTemp
# -2  -2   100.6
# -1  -1   101.5
# 20  20   102.0
plot(AvgTemp ~ Day, data = x2, type = "b", pch = 16)
```

[image: simple line graph]

Alternatively, if you're more comfortable with `dplyr`-based or `data.table`-based solutions:

```r
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  filter(Vaccine == "None") %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarize(AvgTemp = mean(Temperature, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  plot(AvgTemp ~ Day, data = ., type = "b", pch = 16)

library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(x)
DT1 <- DT[ Vaccine == "None", .(AvgTemp = mean(Temperature, na.rm = TRUE)), by = "Day" ]
plot(AvgTemp ~ Day, data = DT1, type = "b", pch = 16)
```